# Bluetooth handsfree better quality

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headphones

Is it somehow possible to get better audio quality sound when Bluetooth headphones are on hands-free mode?  When it is audio only, sound quality is good (16-bit 44 kHz) but when I talk through the microphone, audio quality is changed to poor (16-bit 8 kHz) like an old radio. Or I do not hear something through headphones. I have Creative Sound Blaster Jam.

Simple, have set Bluetooth Audio Renderer (Bluetooth stereo audio), for playing, with Bluetooth Audio Input Device (Bluetooth Hands-free audio), for recording?

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/1104304/is-it-possible-to-use-a-bluetooth-headset-mic-while-having-high-quality-sound?rq=1

Comment: Which bluetooth chipset are you using? Broadcom? CSR? other? and what software you are using to make phone calls?

Comment: See https://www.ipetitions.com/petition/duplex-high-quality-audio-for-bluetooth

Comment: LE Audio should increase quality, but it is still quite rare in spite of spec being finalized a few years ago

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Short:

No

#### Long:

There are so called [Profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles) in Bluetooth, and only one can be active at a time.

**A2DP** supports one-way HQ audio (unless [hacks](https://pulseaudio-discuss.freedesktop.narkive.com/9v1VwPC5/bi-directional-bluetooth-a2dp))

**HSP/HFP** support two-way audio, but only with very poor quality (HFP 1.6 added mSBC, which is a 16kHz mono codec, before, it was even worse).

(ref [http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3399361/bluetooth-headsets-high-quality-audio-microphone-simultaneously.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20170822210130/http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3399361/bluetooth-headsets-high-quality-audio-microphone-simultaneously.html))

(I added the same answer to both [Is it possible to use a bluetooth headset mic while having High quality sound](https://superuser.com/questions/1104304/is-it-possible-to-use-a-bluetooth-headset-mic-while-having-high-quality-sound/1301789) and [Bluetooth handsfree better quality](https://superuser.com/questions/1101560/bluetooth-handsfree-better-quality/1301788) because they are found using google.)

Comment: The tomshardware post says there's not enough bandwidth, which is not correct. Bluetooth Classic supports bitrates up to 24 Mbps, which is more than sufficient to carry two stereo streams with a low-latency, CD-quality codec like Opus at around 192 Kbps each. The total bandwidth use would be under 400 Kbps, or 1.6% of the theoretical throughput of Bluetooth Classic. This would allow reliable transmission even with very low signal strength.

Comment: The Tomshardware post is no longer available.

Comment: so why do Android phones have no issue providing high-quality calls using Bluetooth headsets?

Answer (score 7):

It is *even more* complicated: not only HFP (Hands Free Profile) 1.6 (2011), but even HFP [1.7](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=292287) (2018) consider mSBC codec (the prerequisite for feature called Wide Band Speech - basically sample rate: 16 kHz / 16bit) optional in **both**

- HF (Hands Free - the headphones)
- AG (Audio Gateway - the computer, cellphone).

See Table 3.1, page 19.

Also:

> Since it is only the AG that knows if wide band speech should be used, it should always be the AG that establishes the Synchronous Connection with the required codec.

2.3 d, page 16.

So it is not uncommon that the same HF working perfectly with mSBC under Android AG (e.g. Jabra Elite 65t) fails miserably under Windows 10 with mSBC and all you can do is buying Jabra Evolve 65t for 3x higher price to get the expected result. Or replace Windows with Android...

Oh, you thought of even better quality than mSBC/WBS? Unfortunately, no chance unless somebody comes with "A2DP microphone" :-(

Comment: That somebody would be CSR, and it's called FastStream. Windows (sometimes in very [specific](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9712/wireless-headset-quality/#9714) conditions) was possibly the only place where you could hope to achieve this. And 10 should support both [mSBC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/bthhfpddi/ns-bthhfpddi-_hfp_bypass_codec_id_v1) and [WBS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/bthhfpddi/ns-bthhfpddi-_bthhfp_audio_device_capabilties) anyway, not sure why it'd be severely disadvantaged compared to AOSP.