# limitations of handsfree wireless headset

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bluetooth, microphone, headphones

So I recently bought the sony WH 1000XM3 headset, the audio is great as well as the noice canceling, however I have one big problem. I use the stereo profile when listening to music, however when I want to play games I need my microphone so I have to switch to the handsfree profile. The audio of the handsfree is really bad, is there a way so I can use the microphone and get better sound quality ?

I have done some research and the reason why the sound quality is som bas is because of the HSP/HFP limitations.
[Bluetooth handsfree better quality](https://superuser.com/questions/1101560/bluetooth-handsfree-better-quality)
Is there already a solution to make the sound quality better when using the microphone ?

Comment: That's how it is and always has been. You can use another microphone and keep the headset with A2DP.

Comment: There are claims that Bluetooth 5 will have enough bandwidth to address this issue but I haven't seen a working demo, nor heard much optimism so far

Comment: 2100kbps is absolutely more than enough for whatever audio task you could ever need. This is a problem of protocols, not bandwidth. HFP simply has inferior codecs, and Windows cannot even clear the bar of "half-way decent" because it doesn't support [mSBC](https://www.redpill-linpro.com/techblog/2021/05/31/better-bluetooth-headset-audio-with-msbc.html).