# Does Bluetooth 5 fix the sound quality issues with using headphones audio+mic at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I recently bought a pair of Sony h.ear on 2 bluetooth headphones that include a mic intending to use them to replace the wired headphones I currently use with my late 2016 Macbook Pro (the first touch bar model).

What I did not realize is that Bluetooth (at least up through 4.0) bandwidth is so low that it's not possible to use the mic on the headphones and get good quality audio out at the same time (References [A](https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/), [B](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/heroes/topic/20761927340#post-19), [C](https://superuser.com/questions/1101560/bluetooth-handsfree-better-quality)).

Since one of the main uses I had in mind was voice chat while playing Heroes of the Storm with my friends this was rather frustrating to discover.

[At least one](https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/) of the articles I found are from before Bluetooth 5 was released and mention that it may fix the issue due to the increased bandwidth. Does it?

For example I was thinking about returning the Sony headphones and getting the Jabra Elite 85h headphones (which support Bluetooth 5) combined with a [USB-C Bluetooth 5 adapter](http://www.avantree.com/product-bluetooth-usb-type-c-audio-transmitter-avantree-c51.html) (since my computer does not support Bluetooth 5).

Would that allow me to use the headphones including the mic with reasonable quality?

Comment: It's not about bandwidth, it's about profiles and no, that won't change with newer versions. You've made the same newbie mistake many others have before due to lack of understanding about the different Bluetooth profiles at play here, A2DP (HiFi stereo, microphone disabled) and HFP ("hands free" profile intended for voice communication, mono audio with microphone enabled). You can have one or the other.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia That sounds like an answer to me. I guess rephrasing my question based on that information it would be if any new bluetooth profiles have been introduced alongside Bluetooth 5 that take advantage of the increased bandwidth to allow high quality output without disabling the mic, and it sounds like the answer is unfortunately no.

Comment: @user931000 Do you know of any changes in that regard in Bluetooth 5.2? Thanks.

Comment: I have a "Jabra Evolve2 65", and the trick is that they use their own USB-Adapter using a private protocol. To the computer it looks like a sound card. Also works nicely with Linux (where I never managed to get good quality using Bluetooth).